# Ternary and comma operator

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator, comma-operator

```
int a,b;
a = 1 ? 1,2 : 3,4; // a = 2
b = 0 ? 1,2 : 3,4; // b = 3
```

Comma operator returns always the right side of comma, but if we make an assignment to variable it returns left except the case when we use **()**.
So how the hell the first expression gives the 2.

I see it as a = 1,2 so it should be 1 but actually a=2.

Why?

Comment: Just don't do it. It's probably the compiler punishing you for writing that kind of code.

Comment: My proffesor at university showed us that. And i checked compilers. Msvc, gcc gives the same results

Comment: Comma operator guys. It is not a tuple

Comment: @0x499602D2 I completely forgot about something. It's not UB.

Comment: `b = 0 ? 1,2 : 3,4;` === `(b = 0 ? (1,2) : 3),4;`.. how about that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work

Comment: did u try `0?(1,2):(3,4)` seems like a parsing precedence issue

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's it! How couldn't I saw that. Thanks!

Comment: @user7101876 This is C or C++? Both are very different languages.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Not in this case.

Comment: @Rhymoid fine, but let's learn to learn the difference, shall we? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) (*comma operator having least precedence*), your code actually looks like

```
int a,b;
(a = 1 ? (1,2) : 3),4; // a = 2
(b = 0 ? (1,2) : 3),4; // b = 3
```

So, as per the ternary condition rule, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.15

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated). The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below. <sup>110)</sup>
>
> [...]
>
> <sup>110) A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.</sup>

- For first case, the second operand is evaluated and returned.
- For second case, the third operand is evaluated and returned.